# How to make round circle links responsive in css?

Tags: css, menu, css-shapes

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now. Apparently using % width and height is not enough?

Right now I have fixed 100px width and height and border radius is half of it so it will make it look round. Line height is set to 100px so text would display vertically in the middle of those circles. I have no idea how to vertically center text in another way...

How do I make this menu responsive so it would become smaller as the screen size changes?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu ul {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#menu li {display: inline; float: left;}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px #a2a2a2 solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 5%;
}
```

Comment: learn about `@media` types css ;)

Comment: to align your text vertically just remove your `display:block; line-height:100px;` and add
`display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If  you want true 'responsiveness' you can use the `vw` units which are directly related to the viewport width.

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqzqo5g2/)

Support isn't bad: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

```css
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu a {
  display: block;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px #a2a2a2 solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15vw;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. This is exactly the way I wanted it :)

Comment: +1 most simple technique. For IE8 support the padding technique to keep circle aspect ratio is possible but will be a hassle and require more HTML elements

Comment: Very nice answer :) IE 7 and 8 are always troublesome though.

Comment: True...but IE9< are less than 5% (I think on current numbers) of the market now. Certainly, I don't support them any more and I think that's more and more common.

Comment: How would one add an animated stroke around the circle on link hover?